# Retrieve the last n days from MongoDB file using Python

Tags: python, json, filter, pymongo

I have a code below which connects to a MongoDB database and selects the specified JSON file, flattens it and exports it as a CSV.

So my problem is some of the JSON files in the MongoDB databases are absolutely huge with thousands of rows, so what I am trying to do is filter `table` down so that I only bring in data from the last 7 days.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd
import os, uuid, sys
import collections
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from azure.core._match_conditions import MatchConditions
from azure.storage.filedatalake._models import ContentSettings
from pandas import json_normalize


mongo_client = MongoClient("connstring")
db = mongo_client.nhdb
table = db.Report

document = table.find()

mongo_docs = list(document)
mongo_docs = json_normalize(mongo_docs)

mongo_docs.to_csv("Report.csv", sep = ",", index=False)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Note: I know a way to do it in Azure Data Factory using the expression below, however, I am not sure how to go about it in Python

```
{"createdDatetime":{$gt: ISODate("@{adddays(utcnow(),-7)}")}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python create a datetime object to use as a filter; for example this shows the last 7 days:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
document = table.find({'createdDatetime': {'$gt': datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=7)}})
```